# Why does {1, 2, 3} < {2, 3, 4, 5} return False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

```
a = {1, 2, 3} < {2, 3, 4, 5}
```

`print(a)` produces `False`.

Can you explain me why?

I thought that `a` was supposed to be `True`, as the numbers in the left set are smaller than those in the right set.

Comment: Right, now that the tagging is cleared up, the other question remains: What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought that "a" was supposed to return True, as the numbers in the left set are smaller than those in the right set. But thanks, I have understood now with your explanations.

Comment: I've added that to your question; in future it is always better to explain your expectations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing *sets*, The `<` operator on sets tests if the left operand is a *proper subset* of the right operand, so if *all* elements in the first set are present in the second set, *and* that the second set is larger.

`{1, 2, 3}` is not a subset (proper or otherwise) of the `{2, 3, 4, 5}` set, as `1` is not in the larger set.

See the [`set` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset):

> **`set < other`**
>   Test whether the set is a proper subset of other, that is, `set <= other and set != other`.

No other comparison of the values take place; sets like dictionaries are not 'orderable' so it wouldn't be clear which of the values in one set (keys or key-value pairs in a dictionary) to compare to what values in the other set.

Comment: Might be worth a mention that although this *seems* to work with lists (gives the desired answer with those numbers), it still doesn't do what the OP seems to want

Comment: @en_Knight: we don't know what the OP expected, at all. The expectation that this works like it would for lists would is pure conjecture at this point.

Comment: "I thought that "a" was supposed to return True, as the numbers in the left set are smaller than those in the right set." now we do ;)